# Having trouble printing my theme from a custom module

Tags: 7, theming

I created a custom tpl.php page with some basic HTML:

```
<div id='test'>TEST</div>
```

And a module file that defines the theme:

```
function my_module_test_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
    $items = array();

    //Test
    $items['test_test'] = array(
        'template' => 'test-test',
        'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'my_module') . '/templates',
    );

    return $items;
}
```

But when I try to print it out in my theme it doesn't work:

```
<?php $output = theme('test_test'); ?>
```

Am I printing out the theme in my site's theme's page.tpl.php incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to echo $output.........